# C++ Crash/exception handler in Qt application with thread support on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, exception, crash

I want to make a crash/exception handler for my Qt application. I have the handler working already (not included in the code below). The problem is on Windows that it only works if the crash occures in the same thread where `signal()` and `std::set_terminate()` is called.

On Linux it seems to work for all threads by default.

Is there a way to make it work for all application threads on Windows?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <exception>

void seg_handler(int sig)
{
    // Crash/exception handling code
    // ...
    exit(1);
}

void std_handler( void ) {
     seg_handler(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    signal(SIGSEGV, seg_handler);
    std::set_terminate( std_handler );

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After very much research combined with my lack of knowledge on the Windows OS I finally reached a working solution that automatically sets up terminate functions for new threads.

The trick is to create a dll to handle your crashes/exceptions. In your dll implement the reserved `DllMain()` function. This function receives notifications every time a new thread or process is attached to the main process. The `fdwReason` parameter holds information about the event.

- New thread: `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`
- New process: `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`

Implement your termination handlers in the dll and call `signal()` and `std::set_terminate()` for each thread or process that is started.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  _In_ DWORD     fdwReason,
  _In_ LPVOID    lpvReserved) {
    if (fdwReason==DLL_THREAD_ATTACH) {
        signal(SIGSEGV, seg_handler);
        std::set_terminate( std_handler );
    }
    if (fdwReason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        signal(SIGSEGV, seg_handler);
        std::set_terminate( std_handler );
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

My handlers look like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "StackWalker.h"
#include <signal.h>
#include <DbgHelp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <qdebug.h>

void seg_handler(int sig) {
    // Simple callstack
    unsigned int   i;
    void         * stack[ 100 ];
    unsigned short frames;
    SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
    HANDLE         process;

    process = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );
    frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
    symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
    symbol->MaxNameLen   = 255;
    symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );

    for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) {
        SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );
        printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
    }

    free( symbol );

    // Detailed callstack/crashinfo
    StackWalker sw;
    sw.ShowCallstack(GetCurrentThread());
    exit(1);
}

void std_handler( void ) {
     seg_handler(1);
}
```

The handlers above use [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack)

**Edit:**

Of course you need to add the termination handlers to your main thread as well:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CALL_LOGGER();
    signal(SIGSEGV, seg_handler);
    std::set_terminate( std_handler );
    return runapp(argc, argv);
}
```

Hope this helps someone

-Jakob

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` is a better way of trapping crashes on Windows than `signal`.  It's set globally (so you don't need the DLL to install a handler in each thread) and doesn't discard information about the fault (it's possible there's some way of recovering the true cause of the `SIGSEGV` but I don't immediately know how).

Comment: The nice thing about using signal is that it works on all the platforms my application runs on. I might make som extra windows specific handling though - thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> In a multithreaded environment, terminate functions are maintained
>   separately for each thread. Each new thread needs to install its own
>   terminate function. Thus, each thread is in charge of its own
>   termination handling.

I guess you have to set it separately for each thread.

Comment: This was kind of what I already knew. The problem was that I didn't know how to intercept threads from 3rd party libraries to setup terminate functions for each. I have solved this now and will post it soon.